# netstat no support on this system

Tags: ubuntu, netstat

in dealing with try to resolve another issue into my Ubuntu 22 OS

I need to check out the ports that tightvnc is listening on for connections.

I use this command : sudo netstat -lvp | grep vnc

*BUT this command return me that :*

```
netstat: no support for 'AF INET (sctp)' on this system
netstat: no support for 'AF INET (sctp)' on this system
netstat: no support for 'AF IPX' on this system
netstat: no support for 'AF AX25' on this system
netstat: no support for 'AF X25' on this system
netstat: no support for 'AF NETROM' on this system
netstat: no support for 'AF ROSE' on this system
```

**What is kind of 'support' ?**

**How can I support this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see what you see is because you use the verbose flag. As the manual [`man netstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) states:

```
--verbose, -v
   Tell the user what is going on by being verbose. 
   Especially print some useful information about 
   unconfigured address families.
```

Later the manual explains what `netstat` considers address families:

> `--protocol=family, -A`
> Specifies the ***address families (perhaps better described as low level protocols)*** for which connections are to be shown.  family is a
> comma (',') separated list of address family keywords like inet, inet6, unix, ipx, ax25, netrom, econet, ddp, and  bluetooth.   This
> has the same effect as using the `--inet|-4`, `--inet6|-6`, `--unix|-x`, `--ipx`, `--ax25`, `--netrom`, `--ddp`, and `--bluetooth` options.

The reason those *"no support for 'obscure address family/protocol' on this system"*  are displayed is that some of those address families, low level protocols, although supported by `netstat` are not supported on your system.

**That is expected.**

Not all protocols will be supported on a generic server, often because they are rarely used and/or for example because a particular protocol will only make sense with specific associated hardware.

I had look up the [AX.25 Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AX.25) ; that protocol (like  NET/ROM and ROSE) is designed for use by amateur radio operators and usage on amateur packet radio networks; therefor not protocols that are commonly required to be supported by generic servers.

The kernel docs: https://docs.kernel.org/networking/sctp.html list the Linux Kernel SCTP (Stream Control Transmission Protocol) support as beta, so probably the reason why your Linux distribution also does not enable it by default.

If you want to enable support for those protocols: you will need to explicitly  load the `sctp` or the  `rose | ax25 | x25`  kernel module like below (as root or with `sudo`):

```
# modprobe sctp
```

and the informational message about unsupported protocols should go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still unable to view your TCP and UDP connections using `netstat` try using `lsof -i` and use the `-Po` flags for viewing without port names and reverse DNS names.

Another idea if the above fails, check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203723/how-can-i-list-all-connections-to-my-host-including-those-to-lxc-guests